# How can i test my webpage in different web browsers

Tags: testing, browser

I am designing my webpage and testing it in my default browsers that is IE8 and firefox 3.0.
how can i test it with lower version. Is there anything which i can use to test in all versions.

Iam having problem with  height setting with different version of IE. 
for example my div height is 300px; when i view it in IE8 it looks okay, in IE6 is looks okay but it shows less space in IE7. How can i adjust that.

Any suggestion.

Comment: are you wanting to test interactions as well? for example javascript based effects / ajax ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754991/browser-compatibility-testing

Answer (score 2):

http://www.browsershots.org will deal with whether the layout is as you expect.

If you want to test functionality, then you'll find virtual machines to be your friend.

Comment: It takes tooo much time to get a result from there, not suitable for development phase where you change a small attribute and immediately wants to see a result.

Comment: @Itay Moav, not really, there is no substitute for testing in the actual environment. You can remote in if you absolutely need to refresh every change you make.

Comment: @Itay & @Brian - agreed. If you're developing you need a local copy of the browser, at which point you probably want to go the virtual machines route. For acceptance testing though (which is what it sounded like the OP was after), browsershots.org does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I trust this [Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview for Windows Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for functional web application testing. It is a great tool..

Answer (score 0):

Try using an application called IETester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

It's unstable and buggy as hell but you can quickly test your page in IE6, IE7 and IE8 and even IE5.5 so it's worth having it around.

Answer (score 0):

IE10 has a special section in their developer tools called 'Emulation' which lets you select the browser in which you want the page to be tested in.